# Can't access IP address with 4 digit port number in Mac?

Tags: safari, port, macos-mojave

Im using Mac Mojave, is connected to wifi, trying to access some IP address [52.172.157.225:6034](http://52.172.157.225:6034) in safari, but its failing to load. If I try with double or triple digit port numbers like  [52.172.157.225:80](http://52.172.157.225:80) and  [52.172.157.225:143](http://52.172.157.225:143), it works. what could be the problem and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have make sure that server is actually listening on port 6034(as mentioned in question). Port 80 and 143 are standard ports used for TCP and Email protocols. Hence, they may already be opened.

Comment: yeah,, 6034 port is opened, I checked in windows laptop connected to some other wifi network.. there Im able to access but not in Mac..